# Как разделить статус-дату-время на С++?

Tags: c++, парсер

Программа получает вот такой текст `1:15.06.2016-14:47`
Формат: `статус:дата-время`
Это все нужно разбить.

Comment: Нам важно чтобы вы сами попытались сделать это. Поэтому за вас делать не буду, подскажу лишь, что необходимого результат можно достичь, например, посредством `strtok` (аля _C-style_), либо посредством `std::regex` (аля _C++11_).

Comment: 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: Исправил #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: Бить-то как? По одному символу? По два? Еще как-то? Ну и если формат фиксирован - задача решается парой строковых функций и доступом к элементам строки по индексам.

Comment: может код ваш покажете, как вы это начали делать?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор сам должен постаратся решить проблему

Answer (score 3):

Разбить до какой степени? По отдельной цифре, или на статус-дата-время?

Проще всего - использовать `sscanf` (или `sscanf_s`, если вас напрягает безопасность) - например:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int status;
    char date[20], time[20];
    if (3 != sscanf_s("1:15.06.2016-14:47","%d:%10s-%s",&status,date,20,time,20))
        cout << "Error!\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "Status: " << status << " Date: " << date << " Time: " << time << endl;
    }
    int D,M,Y,h,m;
    if (6 != sscanf_s("1:15.06.2016-14:47","%d:%d.%d.%d-%d:%d",&status,&D,&M,&Y,&h,&m))
        cout << "Error!\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "Status: " << status << " Date: " << D << " " << M
             << " " << Y  << " Time: " << h << " " << m << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ValueTypeVector arr = split(a, ':');//Разбивка статуса
for (const ValueType& it : arr)
    cout << it << " ";
if (arr[0] == 1)//Проверка 1 аргумента 
{
    MessageBox(0, "1", 0, 0);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(0, "0", 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Если вам был нужен только статус, то зачем же спрашивать "это **все** нужно разбить"? :) Только статус - да хоть вызовом `atoi` :)